# calling richtextbox outside the MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

```
public class ThreadExample
    {
        FlowDocument mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
        public static void ThreadJob(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
             mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(Text)));
        }

    }
```

Hi. I have this piece of code. It is situated outside my main window code. What I want is that I will call for my richtextbox to display something based on my needs.

why is it that when I run it, an exception pops that The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an instance of `MainWindow` into your static method. Assuming the `RichTextBox` is in `MainWindow`, just use that reference:

```
public static void ThreadJob(MainWindow mainWindow)
{
    mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(Text)))));
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it is still displaying the same error

Comment: oh. It is working. Sorry I did not notice. :D I tried to start debugging and it shows no error at all. Thanks

Comment: why is it that when I run it, an exception pops that The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: mainWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => mainWindow.richtextbox2.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(Text))));
Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate typE

Comment: YES. It is definitely working. Can you post this also to my other post so that everyone viewing my question will be informed? Thanks so much